# Como leer y capturar datos de un archivo txt haciendo comparaciones

Tags: java, archivo

tengo que hacer un programa que lea datos de un archivo txt. En cada linea del archivo viene un nombre, sexo y 14 numeros enteros que indican en nivel de popularidad de ese nombre durante ciertos años.

Asi, donde cada nombre, sexo y datos estan en una sola linea.

```
Jax M  0    0 0 0   0  0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 347

Randall M 731 974   620 650 467     369 232 70    59  100   136 192 440 841

Minnie F 5 8 22 50  87  122 168 258 516 995 0   0 0 0
```

Mi problema es en la captura de datos. Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica en donde debes escribir un nombre, elegir un sexo con el un radioboton y darle al boton de procesar para que el programa lea el archivo, busca el nombre, y si coinciden ambos, guardar los numeros enteros en un arraylist.
Esto he intentado en codigo.

```
 private void leerArchivo(){ /*Funcion para leer archivo*/
    try {
        Scanner archivo= new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        while (archivo.hasNextLine()){
            String line= archivo.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan= new Scanner(line);

             boolean verificador= false; /*Es para cambiar es estado de la lectura*/

            while (verificador=false){

                nombres= lineScan.next(); /*Aqui se guarda el nombre*/
                sexo= lineScan.next(); /*El sexo*/
                dato= lineScan.nextInt(); /*Los datos*/
                popularidad.add(dato); /*Anadiendo datos al arraylist*/

                /*Mi idea es que si el nombre condice con lo que se pone en el Jtextfield y */
                if (nombres.equalsIgnoreCase(nombre.getText()) && (rb1.getText()==sexo || rb2.getText()==sexo)){

                    prueba.capturarDatos(popularidad); /*Se mandan los datos a un metodo que tengo en otro clase*/
                    verificador= true; /*Se cambia el estado*/


                }

            }




        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
```

De momento tengo que me imprima los datos del arraylist en la consola cuando presiono el boton, pero no pasa nada. Necesito ayuda con que me estoy equivocando o que me pueden recomendar.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El  `while(verificador=false)`nunca te va a entrar ya que el operador "=" es para establecer un valor, tendrías que poner `while(verificador == false)` ya que para comparar valores es necesario el operador "=="